# Can't Seem To Fetch The Authenticated User In Laravel In My Helper Class

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I am a laravel application however i am unable to fetch the logged in user. I happen to log in successfully. The logout functionality works but when i try fetch the authenticated user using auth()->user() or Auth::user() i get null as the return value however it works in the blade.

Sessions get stored alright file or database. Let me know if any extra information will be need to help me debug the issue.

```
public static function getPanelUrlPrefix()
{
if (auth()->check()) {
  $user = auth()->user(); // Retrieve the authenticated user

  dd($user);
  if ($user) {
    $roleName = self::getRoleName($user->getRoleId());

    // Use the role name as a prefix (convert to lowercase for consistency)
    if (!empty($roleName)) {
      return strtolower($roleName . '/' . 'panel');
    }
  }
}

// Default prefix if user is not authenticated or role not found
return false;
```

}

Below is the route where i want to call the prefix

```
$prefix = App\Helpers\Helpers::getPanelUrlPrefix();

// dd($prefix);
Route::group(['prefix' => $prefix, 'namespace' => 'Panel', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () use ($prefix) {

  Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index');
  
});
```

Below is the middleware
[image]

Help will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: The `routes/web.php` file (and other Routes files) create the Routes when the application is started, and there wouldn't be anyone logged in at that point. I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do here, but Route definitions that are dependent on someone being logged in likely won't work...

Comment: I am trying to fetch role_id on the user model based on the logged in user. And then use that role name to prefix the route. I figure as the user is logged i should be able to fetch the current authenticated user anywhere in the system. Any help would be grateful.

Comment: Once again, when the Routes are generated, which is on Application startup (I believe, or at the very least, not "all the time"), **there is no logged in User**. Even when a User logs in later, this `$prefix = ...` code is never run again. You're going to need to rethink your approach here. If all this helper does is add `/{role}/panel` to the Route as a prefix, you'll need to make that Route available **all the time**. I.e. `Route::get('/{role}/panel/', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])` **and** `Route::get('/', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])`.

Comment: Thanks @TimLewis I have refactored my code with a different approach. I appreciate the help.